# Is there a way to obtain a listing of Apex classes, triggers, and components by date?

Tags: apex, metadata-api

I'd like to be able to pull a listing of Apex classes, triggers, and components that have been created or modified after a certain date. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If you are interested in doing this for reasons of deployment, [ASIDE.IO](https://www.aside.io/login) has this type of functionality built into it's deploy (push) screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your aim is to do something manually as a once-off, you can use the "Query Editor" of the "Developer Console" to run these queries (adding `where` and `order by` as required):

```
Select a.SystemModstamp, a.Status, a.NamespacePrefix, a.Name,
        a.LengthWithoutComments, a.LastModifiedDate, a.LastModifiedById,
        a.IsValid, a.Id, a.CreatedDate, a.CreatedById, a.BodyCrc, a.Body,
        a.ApiVersion
From ApexClass a

Select a.UsageIsBulk, a.UsageBeforeUpdate, a.UsageBeforeInsert,
        a.UsageBeforeDelete, a.UsageAfterUpdate, a.UsageAfterUndelete,
        a.UsageAfterInsert, a.UsageAfterDelete, a.TableEnumOrId,
        a.SystemModstamp, a.Status, a.NamespacePrefix, a.Name,
        a.LengthWithoutComments, a.LastModifiedDate, a.LastModifiedById,
        a.IsValid, a.Id, a.CreatedDate, a.CreatedById, a.BodyCrc, a.Body,
        a.ApiVersion
From ApexTrigger a
```

for classes and triggers. But I don't think many/any other components are exposed in this way,  so you will have to use the metadata API for a general solution.

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for. I figured it had to be stored in a table some place as everything is meta data. I just didn't see those objects in a listing.

Answer (score 3):

You have two approaches you can take. One is using the Tooling API and the other is to query for the objects directly in Apex.

---

**Tooling API**

You should be able to get this type of information using the [Tooling API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf). Specifically look at ApexClass, ApexTrigger, and ApexComponent. You can essentially pass a query to it (like the example form the documentation):

```
req.setEndpoint('http://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+id,Body,LastSyncDate,Metadata+from+ApexClassMember+Where+MetadataContainerID=\'+ containerID + '\'');
req.setMethod('GET');
```

---

**Apex**

If you need to explicitly do this in Apex, you best bet is to just query for the objects. As with above, you will want to use:

- [ApexClass](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm)
- [ApexTrigger](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_apextrigger.htm)
- [ApexComponent](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_objects_apexcomponent.htm)

You can then just write a [SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) query with a proper [WHERE clause](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm). So something like:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM ApexClass WHERE LastModifiedDate > :date
```

Answer (score 3):

For recently created Pages and Classes

vf page

```
    <apex:page controller="recent">
      <apex:form >

       <apex:pageBlock title="Recently Created Pages">
         <apex:pageblockTable value="{!pages_creat}" var="page_c">
             <apex:column value="{!page_c.name}"/> 
             <apex:column value="{!page_c.createddate}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!page_c.lastmodifieddate}"/>

         </apex:pageblockTable>
       </apex:pageBlock>

       <apex:pageBlock title="Recently Created Classes">
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!apex_class}" var="ap">
            <apex:column value="{!ap.name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ap.createddate}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!ap.lastmodifieddate}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>

       </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public  class recent {

    public list<apexclass>getApex_class() {
        return [select name,createddate, lastmodifieddate from apexclass order by createddate desc limit 10];
    }

    public list<apexpage>getPages_creat() {

        return [select name, createddate, lastmodifieddate from apexpage order by createddate desc limit 10];
    }
  }
}
```