# Which Apex classes in org are Salesforce Communities-related?

Tags: apex, community, visualforce-component, class

How to find out which Apex classes, Visualforce Components and resources within the organization are Salesforce.com Communities-related? In other words, how to find out which files in the project are Communities-related?

Edit: I'm speaking about standard Communities functionality and classes which were added automatically after activating Communities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is the same behaviour that you get when you activate Sites, where pages and classes and components and static resources are automatically added whether you want them or not.

There is nothing distinctive about these components to separate them from other non-namespace components. Probably the best indicator (until you become familiar with their names) is their Created Date which will be the same for all of them (and correspond to when you activated the feature). In the web setup UI, you can sort or filter by that.

(It is possible to run queries to find components by date too - see [Is there a way to obtain a listing of Apex classes, triggers, and components by date?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28859/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-a-listing-of-apex-classes-triggers-and-components-by).)

If you want to find them to get rid of them, the getting rid of them part is a bit awkward as they include circular dependencies. So it is necessary to e.g. remove references to controller classes from pages before being able to delete the controllers and then you can go on to delete the pages.

Comment: Thanks @Keith C , here's the solution: Select Name, CreatedDate From ApexClass . Using this SOQL query and sorting the results by CreatedDate, I'm  able to see which classes were created when activating Communities.